# Format of string using negative or positive

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, number-formatting

I would like to know if its possible to convert negative and positive strings to use an specific format, with a line of code.

"-1.80" into "-18.00"

or

"1.80" into "18.00"

Comment: you should first convert the string to a number type, like float or double, then multiply it by ten, then convert it back to a string

Comment: How is that a change in format?  You're changing the actual number.

Comment: If you want to affect formating (not actual value). See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the string into a numeric datatype and then multiply this by ten and format this data type:

```
    Dim stringValue As String = "-1.80"
    Dim doubleValue As Double
    Dim outputString As String
    If Double.TryParse(stringValue, doubleValue) Then
        outputString = (doubleValue * 10).ToString("0.00")
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Value could not be parsed")
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(outputString)
```

This will work with both negative and positive numbers